# How to add extra fields in Paypal subscription click method?

Tags: php

Here is my code. I need to add some extra variables example: license-type:Basic

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="business@email.com">

<!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">

<!-- Identify the subscription. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alice's Monthly Digest">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="DIG Weekly">

<!-- Set the terms of the recurring payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="69.95">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

<!-- Set recurring payments to stop after 6 billing cycles. -->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="6">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
```

How to add extra field in this methods ? or I need next line in description tab.!!

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name=" license-type:Basic" value=" license-type:Basic">` like that ?

Comment: at least i want new line in `<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="text text text text text">'

Answer (score 1):

This is an example

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_options_help_outside
```

Add this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom_input" value="Custom value" />
```

Comment: You only need add the next code:

<input type="hidden" name="inputname" value="input value">

Comment: are you check out your code...? i need http://tamilnaduschoolofbanking.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/quesy.png

Comment: Check it out... and go to: option_selectn
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Comment: at least i want item_name value in new line..?

Comment: Add this:
`<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Name">`

Comment: i want new line in value="item name <br/> dddd </br/>" how to work?

Comment: i am using this method also but not working..? i want next next line..!

Answer (score 0):

Please add this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="your custom value">
```

Comment: i need http://tamilnaduschoolofbanking.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/quesy.png this view..?

Comment: custom variable only retun for PDT view page but i want checkout page... options..?

Answer (score 0):

this is an answer..!!!

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="INDIANJOBTIPS">
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Duration">
<input type="hidden" name="os0 " value="1 year">
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="No of users">
<input type="hidden" name="os1 " value="1">
```